# C - cache line and processes performances?

Tags: c, performance, caching, process

### context

I am doing some trials with memory caching. Read a lot of papers.

The problem is not how to make cache friendly code per process, I almost got it.

#### My main concern is : how will the cache behave when, say, hundreds of running processes will hit the L1 cache?

Since L1 size is scarce, should I understand that there will be a lot of cache eviction that will slow other processes since all the processes will fight for L1 cache?
On a cpu with 64bytes cache line and 64k l1 cache with a word size of 64bit.

This is the point I don't understand.

## edit:

The hundreds are per core

Comment: Running hundreds of processes alone is not a good idea performance-wise. The OS will lose loads of cycles swapping processes in and out. Are there ways you could minimize the number of processes and bring them close to the number of cores for example.

Comment: +1 it is stupid you are right :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you'll likely use a multicore CPU. That means you have far fewer processes per core. Modern OS'es try to keep cores and processes somewhat associated, too.

But that said, you indeed lose L1 cache when your program is swapped out. It doesn't even make sense to hold on to it. Your address 0x04000000 doesn't have the same content as the same address in another process. They're virtual addresses.

Comment: In case of hundreds by cpu core they will fight and reduce overall performance right?